# Is apache Jclouds compatible with quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus, jclouds

8.1 and trying to use JClouds 2.2.1 But I get the below exception:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: forcing TieredStopAtLevel to full optimization because JVMCI is enabled
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class io.quarkus.deployment.dev.JavaCompilationProvider$RuntimeUpdatesClassVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:150)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class io.quarkus.deployment.dev.JavaCompilationProvider$RuntimeUpdatesClassVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:400)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:363)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.JavaCompilationProvider.getSourcePath(JavaCompilationProvider.java:94)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.ClassLoaderCompiler.findSourcePath(ClassLoaderCompiler.java:185)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.retrieveSourceFilePathForClassFile(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:352)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.checkForClassFilesChangesInModule(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:314)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.checkForChangedClasses(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:280)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:347)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:129)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm using Gradle and this is the dependency config:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-jib'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler'
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-mssql'

    implementation 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55'

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8'

    implementation 'org.apache.jclouds:jclouds-all:2.2.1'

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}
```

I'm looking through the dependency trees there so many so it's hard to tell which one it is...

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Quarkus 1.9.0.CR1 Seems to accept the Jclouds dependency.